# Connect to Informix database using SQL Management Studio

Tags: informix

Is there a way to connect to an Informix database using Sql Management studio?  Are there any open source / free clients that can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try sqldbx which should work with Informix and is free for single connection use.  according to their faq it works with Informix:

http://www.sqldbx.com/faq.htm